# c++11 Xcode error: expected unqualified-id constexpr

Tags: xcode, c++11

I am trying to write some c++11 code in my mac but I am having some problems. I have verified Xcode version and it is 9.0.1 (xcodebuild -version). When I try to compile a simple code using things like "double ener {9.1234}" or use constexpr it doesn't work. Why? Someone can help me, please.

Best regards and thanks.
Luis

Comment: did you add the flag `-std=c++11` to your makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project target's **Build Settings** and make sure that the **C++ Language Dialect** is set to your desired preference (such as C++/GNU 11 or higher). Although I'd suspect that Xcode 9 would already use C++ 11 as a minimum, but not sure.